# Change data from wide to long format in r

Tags: r, reshape

I have data where students are rated by two raters each on multiple questions. Each row contains these variables:

- student ID,
- the ID for the first rater for the first item
- the rating assigned by the first rater for the first item,
- the ID for the second rater for the first item
- the rating assigned by the second rater for the first item

....and then it repeats for multiple items.

It looks something like this:

```
Student_ID  <- c(1:4)
Item1_first_rater_id <- c(1,2,1,2)
Item1_first_rating <- c(2,3,4,2)
Item1_second_rater_id <- c(2,3,2,3)
Item1_second_rating <- c(4,5,3,2)
Item2_first_rater_id <- c(4,2,5,1)
Item2_first_rating <- c(2,3,4,2)
Item2_second_rater_id <- c(6,7,2,3)
Item2_second_rating <- c(3,4,5,4)

wide <- data.frame(Student_ID, Item1_first_rater_id, Item1_first_rating, 
                          Item1_second_rater_id, Item1_second_rating, 
                          Item2_first_rater_id, Item2_first_rating, 
                          Item2_second_rater_id, Item2_second_rating)
```

I need the data to be in a long format like this:

```
Student_ID  <- c(1:4)
Item_number <- c(1,1,2,2)
Rater_id <- c(1:4)
Score <- c(2,3,4,5)
long <- data.frame(Student_ID, Item_number, Rater_id, Score)
```

Any ideas about how to reshape?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want, especially since your `Item1_first_rated_id` and `Item1_second_rater_id` have common elements. At the very least post your complete `long` table for the `wide` table you gave. Also, is `Student_ID` assumed to be the row numbers in `wide`?

Comment: Editing to put `Student_ID` as first column in `wide`. Doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.I need multiple lines per student, with one rater/student observation in each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't totally clear what you're trying to do (in other words, how exactly you want to transform your source data). Here is one guess that might at least get you closer to your desired output.

It seems like the `names` in your "wide" dataset contain three sets of information: (1) an item number, (2) a "time" (first or second), and (3) another variable (either "rating" or "rater id").

We can use `melt`, `colsplit`, and `dcast` to facilitate our reshaping.

#### Step 1: `melt` the dataset

```
library(reshape2)
orignames <- names(wide) # Store the original names so we can replace them
names(wide) <- gsub("Item([0-9])_(.*)_(rater_id|rating)", 
                    "\\1\\.\\2\\.\\3", names(wide))
# "melt" the dataset
m.wide <- melt(wide, id.vars="Student_ID")
head(m.wide)
#   Student_ID         variable value
# 1          1 1.first.rater_id     1
# 2          2 1.first.rater_id     2
# 3          3 1.first.rater_id     1
# 4          4 1.first.rater_id     2
# 5          1   1.first.rating     2
# 6          2   1.first.rating     3
```

#### Step 2: Create the new columns using `colsplit`

```
m.wide <- cbind(m.wide, 
                colsplit(m.wide$variable, "\\.", 
                         c("Item", "Time", "Var")))
head(m.wide)
#   Student_ID         variable value Item  Time      Var
# 1          1 1.first.rater_id     1    1 first rater_id
# 2          2 1.first.rater_id     2    1 first rater_id
# 3          3 1.first.rater_id     1    1 first rater_id
# 4          4 1.first.rater_id     2    1 first rater_id
# 5          1   1.first.rating     2    1 first   rating
# 6          2   1.first.rating     3    1 first   rating
```

#### Step 3: Use `dcast` to reshape the data

```
dcast(m.wide, Student_ID + Item ~ Time + Var, value.var="value")
#   Student_ID Item first_rater_id first_rating second_rater_id second_rating
# 1          1    1              1            2               2             4
# 2          1    2              4            2               6             3
# 3          2    1              2            3               3             5
# 4          2    2              2            3               7             4
# 5          3    1              1            4               2             3
# 6          3    2              5            4               2             5
# 7          4    1              2            2               3             2
# 8          4    2              1            2               3             4
```

Switching what's to the left and what's to the right of the `~` will affect the "shape" of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems to work. If I wanted to reshape data in this same format that had four items instead of two, which part of the code should I modify? It's simple enough to reshape the two additional items separately and then combine both files, but I would like to know how to build it in to this procedure.

Comment: @windy, I don't quite follow your follow-up question. You might want to read Hadley Wickham's [paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) and [presentation](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data-pres.pdf) about "tidy data". That should help you think about how to get started with restructuring your data to make it more easy to use and manipulate. (Hadley's the author of the "reshape2" package.)